# A programming language that can only implement computable bijective functions?

Tags: reference-request, programming-languages, logic, reversible-computing

Are there programming languages(or logic) that can implement(or express) a function $f:\mathbb{N}\to \mathbb{N}$ if and only if $f$ is a computable bijective functions?

Comment: Somebody proved to me that it is impossible to create a language that accepts only terminating programs. Since you question is pretty similar, I guess no.

Comment: It seems unlikely there would be such a programming language, I guess you could try to enforce it, but then you wouldn't be able to do simple things like sorting, at least not without it becoming horribly complex and painful.

Comment: @FUZxxl This doesn't capture many terminating programs, In fact even the function f(x)=1 is impossible to express in this language. Also I have a feeling this kind of functions are captured by total functional programming since every function is a total function.

Comment: @FUZxxl, I don't think that's right, but such a language would have to be limited. For example, a language that was equivalent to Finite deterministic automata would be guaranteed to terminate, but would be extremely limited in what it could calculate.

Comment: @FUZxxl, the details of such a statement are important. It is easy to design a programming language in which every program terminates. It is a different matter to design a language which we can express every computable function.

Comment: @jmite, while (true) do skip od is a finite state program that does not terminate. Finite automata definable is not the same as terminating.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that if you're looking to compute all *in*jective computable functions then there are several options available, including [Janus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Janus_(programming_language)#Time-reversible_Computing) and several more modern reversible programming languages, many of which can be found by searching for "functional reversible language". A nice theoretical framework is given by [Axelsen and Glück](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-3-642-19805-2_4#page-1).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no such language.

However, have a look at [Boomerang](http://www.seas.upenn.edu/~harmony/). It is a language for writing bijections between strings. I do not know how wide a class of maps is expressible in it, but I am sure you can find out if you search a bit.

It is reasonable to require of a programming language that the set of valid programs be recognizable by an interpreter or a compiler, i.e., that it be a computably enumerable set. Suppose then we had a programming language whose set of valid programs were computably enumerable and which implemented precisely all computable bijections $\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$. That would imply that we can computably enumerate all computable bijections (simply enumerate all valid programs in this programming language), but this is impossible by the next theorem.

**Theorem:** *Suppose $f_0, f_1, f_2, \ldots$ is a computable sequence of computable bijections. Then there is a computable bijection which is not in the sequence.*

*Proof.* We construct a bijection $g : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ as follows. To define the values $g(2 k)$ and $g(2 k + 1)$, we look at $f_k(2 k)$:

- if $f_k(2 k) = 2 k$ then set $g(2 k) = 2 k + 1$ and $g(2 k + 1) = 2 k$,
- if $f_k(2 k) \neq 2 k$ then set $g(2 k) = 2 k$ and $g(2 k + 1) = 2 k + 1$.

Clearly, for every $k \in \mathbb{N}$, $g$ is different from $f_k$ because $g(2 k) \neq f_k(2 k)$. Furthermore, $g$ is computable and it is a bijection because it is its own inverse. QED.

Comment: Why do you even need this $2k$ and $2k+1$ trick? Using $g(k)=f_k(k)+1$ should suffice.

Comment: @FUZxxl: if you use $f_k(k)+1$ the resulting function is not surjective

Comment: You need to make sure that $g$ is bijective.

Comment: The initial statement is wrong, there are many such languages in the literature.

Comment: On the other hand your proof seems legit. Perhaps I'm confused somehow. I need to read Axelsen and Glück's paper (see my answer) carefully to figure out what's going on here.

Comment: Gah. Reversible Turing machines compute all computable *in*jective functions, not all computable bijective functions. I've deleted my answer. +1, and thanks for making me realise something I might not have otherwise. (Axelsen and Glück's paper, which I referred to above, is http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-3-642-19805-2_4#page-1)